# How to count the unselected items in list

Tags: javascript

In these code I can get the selected items, how about the unselected?

```
 <select multiple="multiple" class="multi-select" id="clientIdList" name="clientIdList">
                           @{
                               foreach (var client in Model.ClientLists)
                               {
                                   <option @(client.IsChecked ? "selected" : "") value="@client.ClientId">@client.ClientName</option>
                               }
                           }
                       </select>

     var foo = document.getElementById('clientIdList');
    if (foo) {
        if (foo.selectedIndex < 0) {
            ShowError('Please select client', 'divNotiMailBoxSetting');

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: What is the element with the `id` of `'clientIdList'`? A list (`<ul>`, `<ol>` or `<dl>`) or a `<select>` element? Incidentally, if you *show your HTML* it makes it easier for you to get answers.

Comment: @DavidThomas <select>

Comment: Thank you; now please [edit] your question to include the relevant HTML.

Comment: @DavidThomas <select multiple="multiple" class="multi-select" id="clientIdList" name="clientIdList">
                               @{
                                   foreach (var client in Model.ClientLists)
                                   {
                                       <option @(client.IsChecked ? "selected" : "") value="@client.ClientId">@client.ClientName</option>
                                   }
                               }
                           </select>

Comment: No: *[edit] your question to include the relevant HTML.* There's a link in (both) of my comments to do so, and beneath the tags to your question which also allows you to do so. Incidentally, that isn't HTML, that's a scripting language that *generates* the HTML. What do you see when you right-click and 'view source'? *That's* what we'd need to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get the number of unselected `<option>` items from a `<select>` element:

```
// get all the option elements from the select element with the given id:
var opts = document.getElementById('clientIdList').options,
// create an object of arrays to contain the selected and unselected elements:
    choices = {
        'selected' : [],
        'unselected' : []
    };

// using Array.prototype.forEach to iterate over the NodeList of option elements:
[].forEach.call(opts, function (optElement) {
    // adding the current optElement to the selected, or unselected, array depending
    // on whether it's selected or unselected:
    choices [optElement.selected ? 'selected' : 'unselected'].push(optElement);
});

// assigning the length of the array of unselected elements to a variable for use,
// or to be returned to the calling context (if this is used inside of a function):
var unselectedElements = choices.unselected.length;
```

Without more idea of what you're doing, though, I have to leave it to you to implement that in your function; however a simple use-case is illustrated in this [JS Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dxkhtdkn/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dxkhtdkn/1/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: I'm glad to have helped; but in future *please* take the time to make your question more understandable (and provide the relevant code in advance) to save time for you and those trying to help. Do consider accepting the answer if it answered your question, but it's not obligatory and should be awarded to the answer that most or best helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You may use length property:

```
foo.selectedIndex.length
```